# Как расположить 2 view в одном controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, model

Работаю в ASP.NET MVC. Нужно создать страничку с отзывами, а так же форма для добавления отзывов должна находиться на этой же страничке, как это сделать?

Comment: View всегда отдается 1 per action. Но ты можешь внутри view добавить partial view с формой для добавления отзывов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На стороне контроллера это будет выглядеть примерно так

```
[HttpGet] /* этот атрибут можно и не писать, тк он работает по умолчанию */
ActionResult Comments() {
  ...
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
ActionResult PostComment(string commentText) {
  ...
  return RedirectToAction("Comments");
}
```

Get запрос будет выдавать страничку с отзывами + форму для отзывов

Post запрос обрабатывает написанный отзыв и перебрасывает на страницу коментариев

Вьюшка `comment.cshtml`

```
...
@using(Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) {
  ...
}
```